# Can i parse SQL query using vb.net?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, parsing

I want to convert my MySQL to MSsql using an automated program using vb.net. Do you have any links or parsing engine that could parse Mysql?

I heard i could be done with regex, but the process is somewhat confusing.
Please Help.

Comment: SQL's SQL... unless you're using MySQL-specific syntax extensions or functions, the query should work on the MSSql side. And if you are using mysql-only functions, you most likely won't be able to do a simple 1:1 conversion with any kind of regex/parser.

Answer (score 1):

My experience with both: blah. They really do things in a way that is frustratingly different, and any "tool" meant to streamline this process is going to mean more debugging and rabbit-holing than is worth. This is a penny-wise, pound-foolish equation, IMHO.

If it really is complex, consider porting to ADO.NET or some other connector library that abstracts the actual SQL generation away from the code itself. Otherwise, just do it manually and test, test, test, and retest. My understanding of both is it's not worth it to "automagicallymate it".